# Is the vector field preservative?

Tags: calculus, integration

We have the vector field $\vec{F}=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+2x+y^2+z^2, x^2+y^2+2y+z^2, x^2+y^2+z^2+2z)$.

I want to check if $\vec{F}$ is conservative and to compute the integral $\int_C\vec{F}\cdot ds$, where $C$ is the curve $\vec{\sigma}(t)=(t^2, t^3, t^4), -1\leq t\leq 1$.

$$$$

I have done the following: 
$$\nabla \times \vec{F}=\vec{i}(R_y-Q_z)-\vec{j}(R_x-P_z)+\vec{k}(Q_x-P_y)$$ 
where $P=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+2x+y^2+z^2), \ Q=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+2y+z^2), R=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+z^2+2z)$.

We have the following: \begin{align*}&R_y=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+z^2+2z)+e^{x+y+z}2y  \\ & Q_z=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+2y+z^2)+e^{x+y+z}2z  \\ & \Rightarrow R_y-Q_z=0 \end{align*} 
\begin{align*}&R_x=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+z^2+2z)+e^{x+y+z}2x  \\ & P_z=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+2x+z^2)+e^{x+y+z}2z  \\ & \Rightarrow R_x-P_z=0 \end{align*} 
\begin{align*}&Q_x=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+z^2+2y)+e^{x+y+z}2x  \\ & P_y=e^{x+y+z}(x^2+y^2+2x+z^2)+e^{x+y+z}2y  \\ & \Rightarrow Q_x-P_y=0 \end{align*}

So, we conclude that $\nabla\times \vec{F}=0$.

A vector field is conservative when $\nabla\times \vec{F}=0$ and it is possible to find a function $\Phi(x,y,z)$ such that $\vec{F}=\text{grad}\Phi \iff \frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{x}}=P, \frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{y}}=Q, \frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{z}}=R$, right?

How can we find the function $\Phi$ ?

For the second part with the integral I have done the following: 
\begin{align*}\int_C\vec{F}\cdot ds&=\int_{-1}^1\vec{F}(r(t))\cdot r'(t)dt \\ & =\int_{-1}^1e^{t^2+t^3+t^4}\left (t^4+2t^2+t^6+t^8, t^4+t^6+2t^3+t^8, t^4+t^6+t^8+2t^4\right )\cdot \left (2t, 3t^2+4t^3\right )dt \\ & = \int_{-1}^1e^{t^2+t^3+t^4}\left (2t^5+2t^3+2t^7+2t^9+3t^6+3t^8+6t^5+3t^{10}+4t^7+4t^9+4t^{11}+8t^7\right )dt \\ & = \int_{-1}^1e^{t^2+t^3+t^4}\left (4t^{11}+3t^{10}+6t^9+3t^8+14t^7+3t^6+8t^5+2t^3\right )dt\end{align*}

Is it correct so far? How could we continue?

Comment: I think you mean "conservative".

Comment: Since you’ve shown that the vector field is conservative, you know that the value of its path integral depends only on the endpoints of the path. Can you find a path between $(1,-1,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ that simplifies the integrand?

Comment: So, to show that the field is conservative, we have just to show that $\nabla \times \vec{F}=0$ ? We don't have to find a function $\Phi$ such that $\vec{F}=\text{grad}\Phi$, do we ? @amd

Comment: Ah ok, I will change it @BobaFret

Comment: $\vec F$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^3$, which is simply-connected, so having zero curl is equivalent to being conservative. It’s not necessary to do so, but it is pretty easy to find an antiderivative of $\vec F$ (one can pretty much do so by inspection), which makes computing the integral even easier—you only have to evaluate this function at the two endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec F$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^3$. This is simply connected, so being irrotational is equivalent to being conservative: you’ve shown that $\nabla\times\vec F=0$, so there’s no need to actually find a scalar field $f$ such that $\nabla f=\vec F$ to conclude that $\vec F$ is conservative.

Now, you can certainly slog through the path integral computation directly (it builds character), but I think the point of this exercise is to take advantage of the path independence of $\vec F$. This allows you to choose *any* path between $(1,-1,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ for the integral. An obvious one to try is $\gamma:t\mapsto(1,t,1)$, $-1\le t\le1$. For this path $ds=(0,1,0)\,dt$ and the integrand becomes $e^{t+2}(t^2+2t+2)$, which is a lot easier to deal with than the original integrand.

However, you can make this even simpler. Path-independence of $\vec F$ means that $\int_C\vec F\cdot ds=f(b)-f(a)$, where $f$ is some scalar function such that $\nabla f=\vec F$ and $a$ and $b$ are the end points of $C$. One can pretty much find such a function for this $\vec F$ by inspection, but I’ll do it a bit more systematically. Write $\vec F$ as a vector of scalar functions $(P(x,y,z),Q(x,y,z),R(x,y,z))$. $P={\partial f\over\partial x}$, so start by integrating $P$ with respect to $x$: $$\begin{align} (x^2+2x+y^2+z^2)e^{x+y+z} &= (x^2+y^2+z^2)e^{x+y+z}+2xe^{x+y+z} \\ &= (x^2+y^2+z^2){\partial\over\partial x}e^{x+y+z}+e^{x+y+z}{\partial\over\partial x}(x^2+y^2+z^2) \\ &= {\partial\over\partial x}\left[(x^2+y^2+z^2)e^{x+y+z}\right] \end{align}$$ therefore $f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)e^{x+y+z}+g(y,z)$. Taking partial derivatives of this with respect to $y$ and $z$ and comparing them to $Q$ and $R$, respectively (or simply noting the symmetry of $\vec F$ and $f$ with respect to their parameters) shows that $g(y,z)$ must be a constant, so we have our antiderivative. Finally, $$\int_C\vec F\cdot ds=f(1,1,1)-f(1,-1,1) = 3e^3-3e = 3e^2(e-1),$$ which should match the answers that you get by evaluating the two integrals directly.

Comment: Thank you so much!! :-)